# Why Ajax.BeginFom does not exit?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I already installed Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax.
It says: The name 'Ajax' does not exist in the current context.

The Controller Class:

```
 public ActionResult SimpleInterest()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And the View:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Calculate Simple Interest</legend>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SimpleInterest", "Employee", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divInterestDeatils" }))
{
    <div id="divInterestDeatils"></div>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.Label("Amount")
            @Html.TextBox("txtAmount")
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.Label("Rate")
            @Html.TextBox("txtRate")
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.Label("Year")
            @Html.TextBox("txtYear")
        </li>
    </ol>
    <button>Calculate</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to  install AspNet.Mvc nuget package.

Run the `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` in the NuGet Package Manager Console or Install using nuget package manager it should solve your problem

Comment: I installed it, and put @using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax to the view, the AjaxOptions works now fine, but the Ajax.BeginForm still not working...

Comment: @WolfAlexander Uninstall and install package again it will work